# Question about too much clever answers in math stack exchange

Tags: discussion

I understand the rules to ask a question here. When I ask a question, I try to show what I did and want someone to help me find my mistakes. But then why giving me points down for not understanding something instead of help me understand that? Giving me clever answers don't help me understand anything about my mistakes. Should I get points down for wanting to understand the meanings of these clever answers here? Why not being clear of what you're saying?

Comment: What do you mean by "clever answers?"

Comment: By clever answer I meant answer that doesn't make any sense for me to understand and only the person who is answering the question knows what s/he is talking about. I am not a mind reader you know!

Comment: Look at the five questions you posted in MSE. there are totally 3 answers and none of them is really something "clever" in your sense...

Comment: The people who commented and answered your question are also not mind readers.  Apparently, they didn't know how much you didn't know.

Comment: Wow it's really easy to criticize others when you exactly don't bother reading the full question. Every question I asked, I really try to explain in details. And, not all the answers I said were very clever but maybe some of it. FYI, I don't play any mind reading game here.

Comment: How did you know that that the commenters "exactly don't bother reading the full question"?

Comment: I know that from their answers.

Comment: I upvoted this meta question.  It seems that you're new to the site.  Note that it is always difficult to teach someone if you do not know how much that person knows.  These people who are trying to help you with your question are making these comments and answers to see how much you know.  Right now, it seems that they assume you know much more.  It is normal that you are offended by this.  If, in the future, they assume you know much less, it would also be normal to be offended by this.  I recommend that you stick around the site a little longer to get to know how to get the right match.

Comment: @user136422 Please keep comments polite. I'm giving you broad leeway here since I try to avoid deleting comments on meta and English may not be your first language, but please be nice.

Comment: Wow you people really like to fight. Don't worry I am deleting my own question.

Comment: I don't see it deleted yet. And @AlexBecker wasn't "fighting".

Comment: @Sabyasachi Users cannot delete their own questions if they already have an upvoted answer.

Comment: @AlexBecker ah you're right. I remember now. OP is very impolite though.

Comment: ok give me points down for this post if you don't like. But, why are you taking off points from my other posts? That's not fair. And, if you guys don't want me getting any help from this site, I can remove myself.

Comment: Don't get so upset, those down-votes are probably unrelated, your questions are a bit confusing. If they were related to this question on Meta, it would be a highly punishable [voting fraud](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/126829/what-is-serial-voting-and-how-does-it-affect-me). If you prefer, it is also acceptable to [post in your own language](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/1617/what-is-the-site-etiquette-about-i-asking-and-ii-answering-questions-in-a-la).

Answer (score 10):

Hundreds of people may read the question over time, and sometimes a much larger number.  The answers are for them, for you (the question asker), and for the answerers, but not in any particular order of priority.

For example, an answerer might write down a very "clever" argument not with the primary purpose of helping anyone, but to record a nice solution that they know and is not easily found online or in books.  Others might be writing for more advanced readers and not the asker alone.